# How to plot an array using python

Tags: python, arrays, plot, graph, coordinates

I have a graph plotted. I now need to form two random arrays,X,Y of 12 numbers between 1 and 15 . I then have to plot these on my graph. I am struggling. Can anybody help

Comment: Show us your code, please.

Comment: what exactly make you problem? what did you try? Where is your code? What result do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = [4] // X array
y = [3] // Y array
plt.plot(x, y, marker="o", markersize=20, markeredgecolor="red", markerfacecolor="green")
plt.show()
```

Another simple option is to use scatter method like this

```
x_coordinates = [1, 2, 3]

y_coordinates = [4, 5, 6]


plt.scatter(x_coordinates, y_coordinates)
```